Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat discord.js
I'm trying to run a bot via Visual Studio Code, my bot works fine for a couple of minutes before completely breaking with an error that idk how to fix.
My Code:
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });
const TOKEN = ':P';
setInterval(function () {
    var User = [
        "User1",
        "User2"
    ]


    client.on('ready', client => {
        const someFunc = () => {
            var randomUser = User[Math.floor(Math.random() * User.length)];
            var randomUser2 = User[Math.floor(Math.random() * User.length)];
            var randomUser3 = User[Math.floor(Math.random() * User.length)];
            var randomUser4 = User[Math.floor(Math.random() * User.length)];

            var Action = [
                { content: (randomUser) + " rembered ", files: [{ attachment: "./Image/" + (randomUser) + ".png" }] },
                { content: (randomUser) + " forgor ", files: [{ attachment: "./Image/" + (randomUser) + ".png" }] }


            ]

            client.channels.cache.get('1246634621874213007').send(Action[Math.floor(Math.random() * Action.length)]);

            setTimeout(someFunc, 60000);
        }
        setTimeout(someFunc, 60000); 
    }),
    client.login(TOKEN) 
}, 60000);

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

The Error:
node:internal/fs/promises:1026
    binding.stat(pathModule.toNamespacedPath(path),
            ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
    at Object.stat (node:internal/fs/promises:1026:13)
    at DataResolver.resolveFile (J:\Desktop\Folder\R&R Anything 2.0\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\DataResolver.js:131:30)
    at MessagePayload.resolveFile (J:\Desktop\Folder\R&R Anything 2.0\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessagePayload.js:261:54)
    at J:\Desktop\Folder\R&R Anything 2.0\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessagePayload.js:225:85
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MessagePayload.resolveFiles (J:\Desktop\Folder\R&R Anything 2.0\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessagePayload.js:225:56)
    at TextChannel.send (J:\Desktop\Folder\R&R Anything 2.0\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:175:50)
    at Timeout.someFunc [as _onTimeout] (J:\Desktop\Folder\R&R Anything 2.0\index.js:136:62)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat'
}

It worked as expected for about 4-5 minutes before throwing an error I don't understand.

The SetInterval 60000 isn't needed as it can lead to unexpected behavior and eventually crash the process.. You can just have client.on('ready') and you'll find that the code won't throw an error after 4-5 minutes.

@MarcInglis this was it! could you post this as an answer?

@MarcInglis hmm so as it turns out this did not solve my probl, after removing the setinverval i still errored,but it took a while longer.

After further research I found out this error was related to the version of node I was using, this problem no longer occurs after updating.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Consider editing your answer to include the previous (non-working) version and the current (working) version. Otherwise this answer won't be very useful for future readers.

Move client.login(TOKEN) outside the setInterval function: You should only log in once, not every interval.
Avoid nesting client.on('ready') inside setInterval: The ready event should be set up once, not repeatedly.
File existence check: Before sending a file, you should ensure it exists.
Use client.once for the ready event: This ensures the event is only handled once.
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });
const TOKEN = ':P';

// List of users
const Users = ["User1", "User2"];

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

    const sendRandomMessage = () => {
        const randomUser = Users[Math.floor(Math.random() * Users.length)];
        const actions = [
            { content: `${randomUser} remembered `, file: `./Image/${randomUser}.png` },
            { content: `${randomUser} forgor `, file: `./Image/${randomUser}.png` }
        ];

        const action = actions[Math.floor(Math.random() * actions.length)];

        // Check if file exists before sending
        const filePath = path.resolve(action.file);
        if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
            client.channels.cache.get('1246634621874213007').send({
                content: action.content,
                files: [{ attachment: filePath }]
            }).catch(console.error);
        } else {
            console.error('File not found:', filePath);
        }

        // Set the function to run again in 60 seconds
        setTimeout(sendRandomMessage, 60000);
    };

    // Start the interval
    setTimeout(sendRandomMessage, 60000);
});

client.login(TOKEN);


it worked for about 15~ minutes this time before erroring out again.
